# Using sjoin in GeoPandas

Tags: python, geopandas, spatial-join, point-in-polygon, geodataframe

I have a GeoDataFrame with 12.431 observations of geographical units, called *"cities"*. I also have another layer file with points, called *"points"*. Both of them are in CRS: EPSG4326.

I want to create a variable in the GeoDataFrame which indicates if it contains a point from the other file. This is done correctly from my code.

However, when I use `len(df3)` I obtained that my number of observations increase to 12.599. How is it possible? I have explored if I have missing values in any column but I do not find them.

Why the increase of 168 observations?

I need to maintain the same number of observations as in *"cities"*.

This is the code I am using:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

df3 = gpd.sjoin(cities, points[['geometry']], how="left") 
df3['points'] = np.where(np.isnan(df3['index_right']), 0, 1)
 
del(df3['index_right'])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For each point inside a polygon, a new polygon will be created. So a polygon with 2 points in it will become two polygons
in the output:

```
import geopandas as gpd

city = gpd.read_file(r"/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/cities.shp")

#city.shape
#Out[2]: (3, 3)

# city.Name
# Out[9]: 
# 0    Manchester
# 1    Birmingham
# 2     Sheffield

pnt = gpd.read_file(r"/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/pointsss.shp")
#pnt.shape
#Out[3]: (5, 2)

df3 = gpd.sjoin(city, pnt[['geometry']], how="left") 
#df3.shape
#Out[5]: (4, 4)


# df3.Name
# Out[10]: 
# 0    Manchester
# 0    Manchester
# 1    Birmingham
# 2     Sheffield

#Examples of what you can do to process the duplicates:

#df3.drop_duplicates(subset="Name", keep="first") #Delete them
#df3.groupby("Name").count() #Count
```

[image]

Comment: If I understood correctly, my layer "cities" has 168 observations with at least two points. When I apply my code, that observations are duplicated, right?

Comment: If I use df3 = df3.drop_duplicates(subset="Name", keep="first"), it will remove the second observation, but my variable 'Points' will still maintain value 1 for the observation which is maintained in the geopanda. Is this also correct?

Comment: To your first question: yes. Second: I'm not sure what you are asking. You probably want to `.sort_values` to make sure the dataframe is sorted in a way that the first observation is always the one you want to keep